# How to change dateformat in a Jquery date time picker

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, date-format

I am using a date time picker and the date format is in MM/dd/yyyy, I want to change the date format of the calendar so that in the website it displays dd/MM/yyyy

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

I have saved a copy of this script. and this is how I use it

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.js" type="text/javascript" />
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" />
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript" />


    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('.datePicker').datetimepicker();

    });
</script>

  <asp:TextBox ID="txt_SendAt"  class="datePicker" runat="server" />
```

where should I make changes. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
$('.datePicker').datetimepicker();
```

with:

```
$('.datePicker').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

The above should Initialize a datetimepicker with the dateFormat option specified.

Comment: Sorry I just used the formatting in you question, I have changed the above answer to show

Answer (score 0):

All the options can be found [here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) with examples:

```
$.datepicker.regional['custom'] = {     
    dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
};
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['custom']);
```